# About Recyclerview.Adapter and Android Studio

Tags: android

Type parameter 'com.chad.library.adapter.base.viewholder.BaseViewHolder' is not within its bound; should extend 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder'

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

set up your viewholder like this:

```
    class ViewHolder(itemLayoutView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView) {
    // your views here
       
 }
```

Comment: My compiler did not notice this error until after the update. Is it due to something else other than the code? There is no problem with 4.1.2

Comment: Hi, @EmreTemiz, try to explain why and how your code resolves the issue. Otherwise your answer may be downvoted.